# PrimeNg Dynamic dialog data is empty

Tags: primeng, angular13

I am trying to use dynamic dialog from prime ng
What I want to do is to open dialog in `results-table.component.ts` with

```
this.dialogService.open(ResultsComponent, {
          data: item,
          header: item.resultId,
          width: '50vw'
      });
```

and pass `data` to `results.component.ts`

The problem is that if I do this, `DynamicDialogConfig {}` is empty...
...but `header` is CORRECT and is set correctly, width is also set up properly despite it shows `DynamicDialogConfig {}`
Only `data` is not passed to component dynamically inserted into dynamic modal and DynamicDialogConfig is always `{}` even that `width` and `header` are passed properly and applied to UI.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are trying to read it in a correct way?

```
const item = config.data;
```

And not like

```
const item = config.data.item;
```

Also make sure you have dialog module imported in your module.

import { DialogModule } from 'primeng/dialog';

import { DialogService } from 'primeng/dynamicdialog';

....

declarations: [ ...
],

imports: [
....,
DialogModule,
],

providers: [
..., DialogService,
]

Comment: I did it correect way. The problem was that imported module was inside shared module and somehow my module did not see this one. Had to restart everything 'cause it seems that somehow it was cached.